# How do you turn on ICMP on a D-Link DIR 600 router?

Tags: wireless-router, icmp

My WAN has a problem (that issue was described in my question: [how to debug epicly slow wifi but fast lan](https://superuser.com/questions/259634/how-to-debug-epicly-slow-wifi-but-fast-lan)), and it was suggested that it may be of help to turn on ICMP (see laurent's comment)?

How do I turn on ICMP on a D-Link DIR 600 router?

Comment: I think you should give us more detail as to the problem, because we may be able to help a little more.

Comment: i was suggested to turn icmp on here: http://superuser.com/questions/259634/how-to-debug-epicly-slow-wifi-but-fast-lan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enable ICMP on the DIR-600, open your router's configuration and enable *WAN Ping* on this page:

> [Advanced -> Advanted Network](http://www.support.dlink.com/emulators/dir600/101NA/adv_network.html)

Whether or not it will help depends on the problem. If you would like help with *that* problem (or if enabling ICMP responses did not fix it), feel free to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Open a web browser, enter `http://192.168.0.1`, and hit enter. The username and password should be `admin` and `admin` unless you changed them.

Look around for 'ICMP' or maybe 'Filter Anonymous Internet Requests' in the various areas of configuration.

Comment: 1. I know about 192.168.0.1 and 2, the reason i asked is because i can't find it there

Comment: @Smurf64, caution; *“look around for…”* answers often evoke down-votes.